# Windows Phone 8: Localizing the Tile's display name using AppResources.resx

Tags: c#, localization, windows-phone-8, resources, title

Is it possible to bind the Tile's display name to a string in the AppResources.resx file? I'd like to be able to localize the tile title based on the phone's language.

This is the interface to change the Tile title in Visual Studio 2012:
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a MSDN topic about localizing tile:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/ff967550(v=vs.105).aspx

Comment: Thanks :) you'd think it'd be simpler than that though haha